# reduce method to create new list, why undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reduce

This code gives me the answer I want:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var newArr = arrays.reduce(function(newArray, ele){
  return newArray.concat(ele);
});
console.log(newArray) // -> [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

but this code gives me an 'undefined' array:

```
var combine = function(list){
  list.reduce(function(newArray,ele){
    return newArray.concat(ele);
  });
};
var newList = combine(arrays);
console.log(newList); // -> undefined
```

I wanted to make a function that would reduce an array of arrays into a single array, but I cannot save the function into a variable. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to return the result of `list.reduce`

Comment: beat me to the answer as i was typing lol

Answer (score 1):

You forget to return the list

Try like this

```
var combine = function(list){
  return list.reduce(function(newArray,ele){
    return newArray.concat(ele);
  });
};
var newList = combine(arrays);
console.log(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var combine = function(list){
  return list.reduce(function(newArray,ele){
    return newArray.concat(ele);
  });
};
```

Notice the return. The list becomes a single array but you need to return that from the outer most function. That is why you are getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question so I'm marking this community wiki.

If you wish to combine arrays, using `concat` with `apply` will make this a one-liner:

```
function combine(list) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], list);
}
```

If you are using **JavaScript ES6** this also works:

```
const combine = l => [].concat(...l)
```